# Random "Connection reset by peer" erros with docker-compose and uWSGI

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, python-requests, uwsgi

I am trying to run the tests of my application with docker-compose, but I am getting random 'Connection reset by peer' errors when one container tries to make an HTTP call to another container in the same network.

I have the following piece of code in the container A:

```
session = requests.session()
while True:
    session.get("http://container-b:3171/health/")
```

That calls a dummy endpoint on the container B that just returns an HTTP 200. The container B is a Python application serviced by uWSGI.

That loop runs for around 1000 times and then it fails with the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

## What I have found so far:

This problem seems to be related to how docker-compose setups the network. If I bind the container B to a local port and change my code to call `localhost` instead of `container-b` the problem disappears:

```
session = requests.session()
while True:
    # use "localhost" instead of the "container-b" docker-compose alias
    session.get("http://localhost:3171/health/")
```

I also noticed that the problem doesn't happen if I don't use requests `Session` object:

```
def test_bli():
    while True:
        requests.get("http://stub-server:3171/health/")
```

The Session keeps the connection open, so I guess that the connection is being closed after some time (the while loop runs for just a few seconds)

### What's causing the connection to be dropped?

#### Update

Changing the container B from uWSGI to gunicorn fixes the issue.

Comment: Hello, You are probably increasing the load of the destination and as a result the destination starts dropping connections, the weird thing is that using session.get is more optimal than using requests.get and as a result you should be noticing at least same behaviour in both cases. Are you sure that in the case of requests.get you are using the same burst of connections ?

Comment: @KonstantinosKatsantonis Yes, I am sure. I made a minimal setup to test it. The .get version runs indefinitely while the session crashes almost instantly. I am also not sending requests in parallel.